# SNMP prtAlertCode

Tags: vb.net, printing, snmp

I have been trying to get the Alert Code from my printer at work to see what exactly is happening however each time I send an SNMP query it doesn't return any results. I am using SimpleSNMP references.

The printer is a Canon iR-ADV C5045.

This is how I call the function:

```
Dim strAlertCode As String = SNMPQueryGet("1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.7")
```

This is the function:

```
Private Function SNMPQueryGet(ByVal OID As String)
    Dim strResult As String = "True"

    Dim host As String = "192.168.1.202"
    Dim community As String = "public"
    Dim requestOid() As String
    Dim result As Dictionary(Of Oid, AsnType)
    requestOid = New String() {OID}
    Dim snmp As SimpleSnmp = New SimpleSnmp(host, community)
    If Not snmp.Valid Then
        strResult = True
    End If
    result = snmp.Get(SnmpVersion.Ver1, requestOid)
    If result IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Oid, AsnType)
        For Each kvp In result
            If Not kvp.Key.ToString() = "" Then
                strResult = kvp.Value.ToString()
            Else
                strResult = "True"
            End If
        Next
    Else
        strResult = "True"
    End If

    Return strResult
End Function
```

*edit*

Printer MIB PDF: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19613123/MIB_iR-ADV-C5051-C5045-C5035-C5030_v120_non.pdf

Comment: What version of SNMP does the printer use?
Also, are you sure that the dot delimited number is correct? Run a packet sniffer too to see if it's sending anything back at all.

Comment: The setting says it uses "SNMP v. 1". I can turn on "SNMP v. 3" if it is needed. I believe the dot delimited number is correct. What is a good packet sniffer? I haven't done anything like that in years.

Comment: Wireshark is a good packet sniffer. SNMP v1 is good for now. The security features are disabled with means that you're not running into that. Try sending to local host and see what happens. You may have to change your number to be something like your CPU, etc. That would test the correctness of your code. It could be a Windows firewall if you're on Windows. You could also try to send to a different device like a switch or router to see if any other device responds. Does SimpleSNMP allow for fetching all numbers from a device?

Comment: I know I am able to query the printer already. I have been able to get responses back for "hrPrinterStatus" and "hrDeviceStatus". This PDF contains all the OIDs however SimpleSNMP does allow the fetching of all the numbers from the device... I think. This link http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/content/simplesnmp-vbnet contains sample code, GetBulk would get all OIDs right?

Comment: Yeah, GetBulk is the one you want to try out. I think SNMPSharpNet is a pretty good lib. I used that one myself once.

Comment: GetBulk is also just returning nothing.

Comment: What happens if you gradually construct the OID - meaning send over 1.3.6.1.2.1 followed by 1.3.6.1.2.1.43 followed by 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18, etc? As far as I recall, it should send back a little blob of something even if it may not be useful.

Comment: I remember too that SNMP had community names associated with it. I found this documentation too for the printer that talks about setting community names. http://canonkserokopiarki.pl/contents/nw_007/func.html (you probably have it correct already, just throwing it out there.)

Comment: I already tried that and it was no help. It was still returning nothing when using GetBulk.

Comment: The community name is just public which I have set.

Comment: What about a free mib browser? That should point the finger at the printer should it not work there.

Comment: I tried using a free mib browser and it picked up every other value except for anything to do with "prtAlert"

Comment: Rambomst, I searched for your printer model and "SNMP" on Google and found the following link. Take a look at it and search for C5045. I see a "N" in the box for SNMP? Does this make sense to you? http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas1e9bd60440bf30f3c862569c100795cad

Comment: If that is saying that it doesn't support SNMP then that page is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Rambomst: you mention a PDF with all the C5045 OIDs, would you mind sharing the PDF?... i'm looking for those codes!

iReasoning's MIB browser is pretty handy for SNMP debugging: http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml

Comment: I added it to my original post.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it does not mention the print/scan count OID’s, do you have any idea where I can find those?